# How do I load JSON file in CasperJS script to loop through?

Tags: javascript, json, casperjs

I need to load the JSON file and iterate through it in a loop. Here is the json

test.json:

```
[
    ["AA", "1112223333"],
    ["AM", "2223334444"],
    ["BF", "3334445555"],
    ["CP", "4445556666"],
    ["JB", "5556667777"],
    ["TC", "6667778888"],
    ["TT", "7778889999"]
]
```

The Casper script:

```
var casper = require('casper').create({
    logLevel: 'debug'

});

var json = require('test.json');
console.log(json);
require('utils').dump(json);
```

ultimately I see it loading as an array just like the file essentially. Then I will loop through the variable and use the initial and phone number in the script.

Comment: You would do this in the same that you loop through an ordinary JS array. Have you tried `json.forEach()` or a simple `for`-loop? Is there some problem that you're not telling us about?

Comment: @ArtjomB. I'm not hiding any problems. I'm just very very new to Javascript and don't know how to load the JSON in a way that it's usable. I know how it would work in Python...just not JS :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try "each" function ([here](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#each))

Here is an example code.

```
var casper = require('casper').create({
    logLevel: 'debug'
});
var json = require('test.json');
casper.start().each(json, function(self, item, index) {
    this.echo(item[1]);
    // Also you can use index to filter the items inside array.
}).run();
```

Comment: Without knowing what this is for, this seems like an overkill, because `json` is a native JavaScript array and has the `forEach` function. Also, a simple `for`-loop would work too.